# What is a Chatter Post Alert?

Tags: managed-package, chatter

In my packaging org on the page to add components to a package I today encountered a type I never heard of before: Chatter Post Alerts.

What is this? Even a google search did not help ;)

[image]

Comment: It *sounds* like a new Workflow Action.

Comment: In the HTML source for the select the value is `ActionChatterPost`. That doesn't mean much to me, but does tie in a bit with @techtrekker's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's part of the new Custom Chatter Action feature that soon will be released in Summer '13. Here is a screenshot from a Prerelease org :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation on this, but comparing the various options available in the workflow section of setup to the list of child metadata types for workflow from Workbench I'd put my bet on this being the metadata for Approval Post Templates.